# Generating CSV with Spring reactive webflux

Tags: csv, spring-webflux, opencsv, spring-reactive

I have an endpoint that should generate a CSV report with a stream. I implemented the endpoint like this:

```
     @GetMapping(value = "/sessions/csv")
      public Flux<CsvEntity> getCsv() {
        return csvService.exportToCsv();
  }
```

Now I'm getting the response through a stream, but I don't have headers and the data is shown with the field name. 
I tried to use `StatefulBeanToCsv` of opencsv but for that I need a writer. When I used servlets I could initialize a writer with the `response.getOutputStream()` but with webflux I couldn't make it work.

I didn't find any documentation for that. Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think your problem is that right now you are returning a stream of chunks, so you can find a way to create a file with frontend or you have to send a file with the old way. Maybe you can send a Mono<StreamingOutput> or something else? Let me know please

Comment: @firegloves StreamingResponseBody is a servlet class, it can't be used in a reactive context

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, to set this in the  `StatefulBeanToCsv`  and if you have a bean, you write it to beanToCsv, extract the content of baos, reset the baos, and now you are able to push the extracted text to bytebuffer in the response.

Comment: @Yuval what did you end up doing here?  I am currently looking into a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example Controller that returns a CSV file(downloadable) in a browser

*Spring boot + SpringWebFlux*

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/download-csv")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> downloadCsvFlux() {
        String content = "Name,Age\nJohn,20\nJane,20";

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv"));
        httpHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "sample.csv");


        Flux<DataBuffer> csvDataBuffer = Flux.just(content.getBytes())
                .map(DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance::wrap);

        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(httpHeaders)
                .body(csvDataBuffer));


    }
```

Note: The CSV is produced manually but the same can be done using some library like  `opencsv`